# Is there any desktop search engine on Linux that can index including the NTFS?

Tags: linux, ntfs, desktop-search

I am using Arch Linux. I have tried beagle search engine. I can add the /mnt/windows (my NTFS drive) for indexing by beagle. But when I search, there is no result from /mnt/windows. Besides that, I also tried Google Desktop Search, it also does not index the /mnt/windows, even I added it to the setting. Is there anyway to index the NTFS partition, so that I can search the file easier in Linux? Or is there any other method for searching the contents easier?

Answer (score 2):

First, check after mounting NTFS partition permanently from fstab.
Then, try other desktop search tools: [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/), [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/), [Strigi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strigi/)
If there's still the problem, let me know...

Comment: I have also used [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/), [Gnome Do](http://cooperteam.net/) among others as well. None of those seemed to have trouble indexing my NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the mount was actually successful? If you use command "ls -l /mnt/windows", do you see your windows files?

Comment: sure. no problem for me to access any files in ntfs.